# cmd in Visual Studio Code behaves different than cmd in Windows after installing node

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, cmd

My terminal in Visual Studio Code (as powershell) was open before I installed node/npm.

After installation, I tried `npm -v` and `node -v` to test within Visual Studio Code but it failed.

Now I restarted my Visual Studio Code, its terminals etc but while `npm -v` works in cmd/powershell of Windows (10) globally, without any problem

[image]

it is not recognized yet inside the cmd/powershell in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: npm was not included

Comment: So re-open your application so it can reload your PATH.

Comment: I re-opened VSCode as I mentioned in question, but didn't work. So, I had to restart my own host in order to get it work. But it should not be the solution of that problem.